# contar resultados desde el controlador

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Con el siguiente código hago que busque en una BD=payments y si 'fecha_pago' es igual a hoy me lo muestre en la vista. Y según lo encontrado me agregue un contador. Si encontró 2 resultados el valor de la variable $varnum= 2. 
Pero mi duda es como puedo hacer lo mismo sin que pase a una vista, directo del controlador. Mi objetivo es si encuentro 2 que coincidan con “hoy” poderlo guardar en una BD=system->numph. Igual si hay sugerencias en mi código de la vista las acepto por que recién ando aprendiendo.

tengo un controlador (UpdateController.php)

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
$hoy = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$payments = Payment::searchdatepay($hoy)->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(10);
return view('update.update')->with(['payments'=> $payments, 'varnum' => 0]);
}
```

un scope (Payment.php)

```
protected $table = "payments";
protected $fillable = ['loan_id', 'id', 'pago', 'pagado', 'motivo', 'estado', 'fecha_pago', 'fecha_promesa', 'pago_abono', 'pago_adeudo', 'dias_atraso', 'asesor', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function scopeSearchDatePay($query, $var)
{
return $query->where('fecha_pago','LIKE',"%$var%");
}
```

una vista (update.update)

```
@section('content')

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Nº</th>
        <th>Fecha de Pago</th>
        <th>Motivo</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach($payments as $payment)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $varnum = 1 + $varnum }}</td>
            <td>{{ $payment -> id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $payment -> fecha_pago }}</td>
            <td>{{ $payment -> motivo }}</td>
            <td>{{ $payment -> estado }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! $payments-> render() !!}
<!-- Plugins -->                

@endsection
```

Comment: La idea es mostrar un contador de registros encontrados en la tabla de la vista?

Comment: en la vista la tengo, cuando imprimo la variable $varnum tengo los encontrados. pero lo que quiero es no llamar a la vista. que sea en el controlador. para que el resultado lo guarde en una Tabla=system Campo=numph Valor= (lo encontrado). se me entiende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto estás buscando [count()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php), una función de PHP:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $hoy = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $payments = Payment::searchdatepay($hoy)
        ->orderBy('id','ASC')
        ->paginate(10);
    $varnum = count($payments);
    return view('update.update', compact('payments', 'varnum'));
}
```

Le hice una pequeña mejora a tu código, sin embargo hay otras dos mejoras que sugiero:

- No debería ser responsabilidad del controlador obtener datos de la base de datos (o en este caso tener contacto con el Query Builder). Esta parte debería estar delegada a un servicio, job, repositorio o similar.
- Para respetar [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), el cual es usado por Laravel, deberías declarar Carbon con use, algo así:

  ```
  use Carbon\Carbon;

  class PaymentController // ....
  {
      // ...
      public function index(Request $request)
      {
          $hoy = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! y para terminar.
1) me interesa el tema, me puedes proporcionar un link donde explique mejor lo que dices? Para aprender y mejorar mis errores. 
2) Lo segundo ya tenía cargado el (use Carbon\Carbon;)  pero por una extraña razón me saltaban conflictos y no lo llamaba bien. Por eso lo escribía así para no tener errores. Hoy otra vez quite el (\Carbon\) y si jalo… de verdad no me explico. Saludos.

Comment: Aquí tienes un par de enlaces interesantes (en inglés) al respecto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704792/separation-of-responsibilities-php-for-controllers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595036/mvc-laravel-where-to-add-logic

Comment: una consulta, cuando coloco: return view('update.update', compact($payments, $varnum)); ,me salta un error (Undefined variable: payments ) ,pero si lo escribo así: return view('update.update')->with(['payments'=> $payments, 'varnum' => $varnum]);  ,no tengo ningún problema. A que se debe?

Comment: Había cometido un pequeño error en esa parte, ya lo corregí, disculpas!